# CÓMO PODER CONVERTIR TXT A EXCEL EN PYTHON

Tags: python, excel, txt, openpyxl

He desarrollado un método que convierte archivos .txt a formato .xlsx, ingresando dos parámetros (ruta del archivo .txt y el otro es el nombre del archivo en formato de Excel). El problema radica en que no funciona como tal el método, ya que cuando convierte a Excel sólo reconoce 1 columna, o sea lo toma como tan solo 1 columna.

Habrá alguna forma alternativa para poder convertir archivos .txt a formato de Excel considerando filas y columnas?

Muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto!, además cual es el `.txt`? tienes algún error?, ¿por que dices que no funciona? añade una mejor explicación

Comment: @AndersonFuentes, todo código va como texto, por favor sigue las recomendaciones que te da el centro de ayuda: [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), sobre todo en la parte de **Completo**

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque publica código como imagen.

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión te conviene usar archivos csv y aplicar la librería pandas para hacer uso y manipulación de los datos. Sinceramente nose bien como conventirlo mediante python pero con cambiarle la extensión de txt a csv ya es suficiente. Te recomiendo que una vez que cambies la extensión del archivo txt a csv por ejemplo, `hola.txt` a `hola.csv` lo abras en excel y hacer ciertos cambios que necesites.

Comment: Hola! Pandas también acepta archivos `txt`, pero no se como funciona en profundidad, nunca necesite leer un `txt` con *pandas* por lo que no puedo dar más detalles.